# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()'

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and working on a chat app YouTube tutorial. now getting below error in my code. how to resolve this. appreciate your help on this.

[image]

```
class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  const Search({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {


  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  TextEditingController searchEditingController = new TextEditingController();
// QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot;
  QuerySnapshot <Map<String, dynamic>>? searchSnapshot;
 bool isLoading = false;
   bool haveUserSearched = false;

  Widget searchList(){

  return searchSnapshot != null? ListView.builder(
      itemCount: searchSnapshot!.docs.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return SearchTile (
        name: searchSnapshot!.docs[index].data["name"],
        email: searchSnapshot!.docs[index].data["email"],
        );
  }) : Container();

}
```

Comment: What is the data type of your "data": searchSnapshot!.docs[index].data?

Comment: `data` is a function as mentioned here: `Map<String, dynamic> Function()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is a method, not a getter or a field, add brackets like so:

```
  name: searchSnapshot!.docs[index].data()["name"],
  email: searchSnapshot!.docs[index].data()["email"],
```